# How to set a minimum random number in REBOL?

Tags: rebol

I'm executing some code and then waiting somewhere between 1 second and 1 minute.  I'm currently using `random 0:01:00 /seed` but what I really need is to be able to set a floor so that its waiting between 30 seconds and 1 minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want 0:0:30 to be the minimum and 0:1:0 to be the maximum, try the formula:

```
0:0:29 + random 0:0:31
```

This formula yields a "discretely distributed (pseudo)random value". If you want a "continuously distributed (pseudo) random value", you can use (just in R3) the formula:

```
0:0:30 + random 30.0
```

R2 does not have a native support for "continuously distributed (pseudo)random values".

Comment: That's pretty cool.  But if such loosey-goosey semantic things are permitted, then why can't multiplication of percentages and times work?  Isn't 50% of a minute 30 seconds?  I break down a problem like this by considering as a random percent first, and I think that's valid too.

Answer (score 2):

Not my area of expertise, but:

```
00:00:30 + to time! (random 100% * (to integer! 00:00:30))
```

...appears to work, I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>random/seed now/precise
>> t1: now wait 30 + random 30 difference now t1
== 0:00:39
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
0:00:30 + random 0:00:30
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a whole number from 1 to 30 and subtract that number in seconds from 1 minute and 1 second.
(and about seeding, use that, but not constantly)

Comment: That's incorrect, actually, the minimum would be 31 seconds, not 30 seconds.